# Have bootstrap linebreak on specific elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi so I have a bootstrap row with 6 elements in it, currently when the screen is made smaller the elements break onto the next line one by one as the screen gets smaller. I'd like it so that when the screen gets small enough for 1 element to go to the next line it instead breaks into two lines of 3 elements. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
  <div id="elem1">

  </div>
  <div id="elem2">

  </div>
  <div id="elem3">

  </div>
  <div id="elem4">

  </div>
  <div id="elem5">

  </div>
  <div id="elem6">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Include the code too please

Comment: I've added my code

Answer (score 0):

Nest the Bootstrap grid inside of the column...

https://www.codeply.com/go/0W2uXJ9eGG

```
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div id="elem1" class="col-lg-2 col-4">

            </div>
            <div id="elem2" class="col-lg-2 col-4">

            </div>
            <div id="elem3" class="col-lg-2 col-4">

            </div>
            <div id="elem4" class="col-lg-2 col-4">

            </div>
            <div id="elem5" class="col-lg-2 col-4">

            </div>
            <div id="elem6" class="col-lg-2 col-4">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```